# how can use style to my PDF document

Tags: c#, winforms, document

I have a windows form application that connects to database and collects all the data into DataTable and pass this table to PDF and creates a PDF. But I need to put some style to my table on PDF. Like header is  bold. row is different color. etc. is there any way to do that?

```
 using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
            {
                Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);                
                PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, stream);
                pdfDoc.Open();
                pdfDoc.Add(pdfTable);
                pdfDoc.Close();
                stream.Close();
            }
```

Comment: iTextSharp, right? IIRC this is a good tutorial http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/80/create-pdfs-in-asp-net-getting-started-with-itextsharp - and here is the link for font-styling http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/81/itextsharp-working-with-fonts

Comment: Alternatively - and that sound preferrable to me - you can create LaTeX-Markup, compile it and return the generated .PDF